# Merging Woocommerce Checkout Streetname and Housenumber to Address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have two fields in my checkout form, street name and house number, that also has to merge and get in the shipping_address_1 field after checkout. At the moment, they only do for the Netherlands. The reason is that in the order overview in Woocommerce, the shipping address field is empty and I can't export to the shipping company. They need the Street name, House number and Address 1.

site: https://www.rockstar-clothing.com/checkout/

[image: The empty address field]